# If $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ then why are the matrices of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ not rotation matrices?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ then why are the matrices of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ not rotation matrices? They aren't infinitesimal rotations either.
The matrices of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ are skew-symmetric matrices which are the type used to calculate the cross product.

How can $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ be tangent to $SO(3)$ if they're never even in $SO(3)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ be tangent to $SO(3)$ if they're not even in $SO(3)$?

The same way $(0,\frac12)$ can be a tangent vector to the unit circle at $(1,0)$ even though $(0,\frac12)$ is not *on* the unit circle.

One (loose and informal!) way to think about it is that an element of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is the *difference* between the matrix of an infinitesimal rotation and the identity matrix, but "scaled up by a factor of infinity" such that the entries of the matrix don't need to be infintesimals themselves.

Comment: I guess that explains "The matrices in the Lie algebra are not themselves rotations; the skew-symmetric matrices are derivatives". Thanks

Comment: Would the derivative be with respect to time?

Comment: @R.Emery: You can think of it as time if you want. The formalism doesn't care, of course -- it just says that if you have a _differentiable_ function $f:\mathbb R\to SO(3)$ such that $f(t_0)=I$, then $f'(t_0)$ should be in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ -- and all elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ are such derivatives.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I cant vote yet but if I could I would give you a plus one.

Comment: I have quoted you here: http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Infinitesimal_rotations   hoping you are okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is an infinitesimal rotation means that $e^A$ is a rotation.

Consider $e^{tA}$, you have ${d\over{dt}}\langle e^{tA}x,e^{tA}x\rangle=\langle$ $A(e^{tA}x),e^{tA}x\rangle+\langle e^{tA}x,A(e^{tA}x)\rangle=0$ since $A$ is antisymmetric.  You deduce that $\langle e^{tA}x,e^{tA}x\rangle$ is constant ant its value is $\langle e^{0A}x,e^{0A}x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle$.

Comment: $ \langle x,x \rangle $ is the inner product?

Comment: This: http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Infinitesimal_rotations is all I know about that